# Variables not available using wp_localize_script()

Tags: jquery, wordpress

I am attempting to make two variables accessible to a JS script in wordpress using the `wp_localize_script();` function. I'm registering, localizing and enquing my scripts like this, as per the codex.

```
    wp_register_script( 'overview-map-js', '/js/overview-map.js');

    $translation_array = array (
        'latitude' => $location["lat"],
        'longditude' => $location["long"]
    );

    wp_localize_script( 'overview-map-js', 'lat_long_vars', $translation_array );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'maps-cdn', '//maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?v=3.exp&sensor=false' );
    wp_enqueue_script( 'overview-map-js' );
```

However, the variables are undefined within the script:

```
jQuery( document ).ready(function($) {

console.log(lat_long_vars.longditude);
console.log('test');

})
```

The variables are set in PHP. Can anyone suggest what the issue could be here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use relative paths while registering scripts. To solve that:

If you're not using child theme:

```
 wp_register_script( 'overview-map-js', get_template_directory_uri() . '/js/overview-map.js');
```

If you're using child theme:

```
 wp_register_script( 'overview-map-js', get_stylesheet_directory_uri() . '/js/overview-map.js');
```